# Compatibility of wireless cards with the Dell inspiron 15 3542

Tags: wireless-networking, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3542 and would like to use the new wireless ac technology. I was wondering if the Intel ac 7260 would be compatible. Because I know some laptops have WIFI cards tightly bound to the bios

Answer (score 1):

In a word - **no**.

Don't go messing around with your drivers.  Just stick with the ones that Dell ships.  Changing around wireless drivers can leave you unable to use your wireless networking on laptop until you do a full reformat and reload of the operating system.  Intel in particular does *weird* things with the Windows Registry and makes uninstalling and reinstalling wireless drivers impossible.  (I am speaking from personal experience from imaging 30 computers with the wrong Intel drivers and we had to rebuild the system image and reload all the workstations).

You can put your Dell 'service tag' or Dell 'Service Express Code' in here to see if there are new drivers from Dell:
http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04#technical-support

You can go in to the Device Manager for your wireless chipset and look up the exact PCI ID's and determine who the chipset manufacturer is, and the other information, but I advise heavily against this if you have a working system.   The Intel code is 8086.